# Parse Cloud Getting all Users with User Role

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

we have an admin interface so CS can view all users with their role and also they have the option to change user's role for any particular user's
We are using Parse cloud
So, Can anyone tell me how can I fetch all user's with their role, I am fetching users by using this code but unable t understand how to get role belongs to every users

```
Parse.Cloud.define("UserWithRole", function(request, response) {
    const Userquery = new Parse.Query("User");
    Userquery.find({
      useMasterKey: true,
    }).then(function(data){
         /// Getting User List here but I want their roles also
    });

});
```

**Environment**
    "node-schedule": "^1.3.0",
    "parse": "^1.8.5",
    "parse-dashboard": "^1.0.19",
    "parse-server": "2.8.4",

Comment: I want to fetch all of user details with their role in parse cloud

Comment: You mean you need this? https://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/#queries Or are you asking how to build an HTML dashboard based on the returned data? Either way, this question is way to broad and sounds like "gimme the code".

Comment: I have uploaded my code here, by using this code I am able to get list of users in an array, but I also want to get each user with their role for eg.
[
 { Name:  A, Role: Admin, Email: xyz@gmail.com}
{ Name: B, Role: Moderator, Email: abc@gmail.com}
]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```js
Parse.Cloud.define('UserWithRole', async request => {
  const usersQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
  const users = await usersQuery.find({ useMasterKey: true });
  return await Promise.all(users.map(async user => {
    const rolesQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Role);
    rolesQuery.equalTo('users', user);
    const roles = await rolesQuery.find({ useMasterKey: true });
    return {
      name: user.get('name'),
      roles,
      email: user.get('email');
    };
  }));
});
```